# Consuming web services in test environment only

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

There is a set of soap services (built in tibco) that I have to consume in my code. However, those services are only available in our test environment and not in our development environment. How should I add service references in my code so that those services get called only in test environment and not in dev.

Comment: Is your question  _"How can I generate service references of a service that isn't reachable from my machine?"_, or is it _"How can I make code do one thing in one situation and another thing in another situation?"_?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [conditional compilation directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691099%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). These allow you to have different build for different purposes (e.g. debugging and release versions).

You can add your own directives by right-clicking on your project --> open the *Build* tab and enter a term like `TESTENV` (for test environment) in the textbox labled "Conditional compilation symbols".
**Note:** These symbols are *per build configuration*!

Then, in your code, use a conditional compile statement like this:

```
public void CallWebService()
{
    // Does stuff always

    #if TESTENV
        // Does stuff only when TESTENV is set
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a entry in web.config that determines whether the environment is test or dev.
2. In the code have a condition in place to check the environment and then call the web service based on the environment.

Hope this Helps